# Comparison Operator (e.g. eq) from PSObject?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get a comparison like the following to run in PowerShell? `$itm.op` is a value like "eq" in a CSV.

```
1 -$itm.op 1
```

Comment: ``$a = 1; $b = $itm.op; $c = 1; iex "`$a -$b `$c"``

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why do you think you need this? To what end?

Comment: @PetSerAl your example does not work. It is not possible to pass in a comparison operator via a variable in PowerShell.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Any evidence to support your claim?

Comment: @PetSerAl [yeah the error I'm staring at in my PowerShell prompt](http://pasteboard.co/5uR7VOuTs.png). When you put `-$b` in your last string for Invoke-Express, PowerShell is going to try and execute that as a command.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Please read error message carefully. PowerShell complain about `$b = eq` in your code. It is where **you** try to run `eq` as command. It should be `$b = 'eq'`.

Comment: if $itm.op is "eq" string then the answer given by @petSerAl should work ,can you add sample csv and the code used to fetch $itm.op

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for your suggestion. @Esperento57's solution below worked for me.

This is part of a script I've written to validate data in an Excel file based on validation conditions in a CSV file. In this case, $itm.op might be any comparison operator. As an example:

$ct = BR;
$itm.op = eq;
$itm.val = BR;

`$cexp = '$ct -' + $($itm.op) + ' $($itm.val)'`
`$cexp`
`True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Something like this

```
#build your string to evaluate (you can use your object)
$expression='1' + ' -eq ' + '1' 

#evaluate your expression and get result 
$result=Invoke-Expression $expression

#use result
if ($result)
{

}
```